# Java loop divisibility sum and average

Tags: java, eclipse, loops

I have made a loop that produces the sum and average of numbers 1,2,3,...,to an upperbound 100.  What I am having trouble with is modifying my current code so it only includes numbers that are multiples of 7.  Here is what I have:

```
public class SumAndAverageForLoop {

     public void SumAndAverageForLoop() {
         double sum = 0;
         for (double i = 1; i <=100; i++) sum+= i;
         System.out.println ("the average is " + sum/100);

         System.out.println ("the sum is " + sum);

     }
}
```

I am trying to do it without a main method so I had to create a Launcher class.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just as reference - Are you trying to add multiple of 7 and find the average/sum, or additional find multiple of 7? E.g. should your numbers be 7, 14, 21, 28... ? If so you just need to put i=7, and i+=7 in your for loop.

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine if a number is divisible by 7 you should use the modulo devision operator % and compare the remainder to 0;

```
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
        if (i % 7 == 0) {
            sum += i;
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("the average is " + sum/count);

    System.out.println("the sum is " + sum);
```

Also I wouldn't recommend using a double when all you need is an int. You might get caught out by precision issues further down the road. You could cast your sum to a double before dividing to by count if you want a decimal average. Like this:

```
System.out.println("the average is " + ((double) sum)/count);
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to modify the for loop, instead of looping through every number anyways?

Comment: You certainly could increment i by 7 for each iteration and that would result in fewer computations however in such a simple case I don't think efficiency is a concern. I think the root of the question is how to determine if a number is divisible by another number, to which the answer is (a % b == 0) I thought showing that solution would provide the poster of the question with something they would find generally useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8 this is now easily accomplished without writing error prone looping structures as follows:

```
IntStream.range(0,100).filter(i -> i % 7 == 0).summaryStatistics();
```

Result:

```
IntSummaryStatistics{count=15, sum=735, min=0, average=49.000000, max=98}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your for loop should increment in 7's for each iteration and also you should maintain a count of your iterations because you need it for finding average.

```
    int sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int average = 0;
    for(int i=7; i<=100; i=i+7)
    {
       sum = sum + i;
       count= count+1;
       average = sum/count;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I would use the Modulus operator for this use case.

```
public class SumAndAverageForLoop {

    public void SumAndAverageForLoop() {
        double sum = 0;
        for (double i = 1; i <=100; i++){
            if((i % 7) == 0){
                sum+= i;
            }

        System.out.println ("the average is " + sum/100);

        System.out.println ("the sum is " + sum);

    }

}
```

Comment: The OP is trying to avoid writing a class for this.